# How to solve this relation?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Is there a standard procedure to solve something like this?
$$
m-n\equiv0\qquad\text{mod}\qquad 1+m^2-n^2
$$

Comment: Since $m-n<1+(m+n)(m-n)$, surely the only solutions would be $m=n$.

Comment: What if $m = 1$ and $n = -1$? Is $2 < 1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking to see if there exists $k$ satisfying $k(1 + m^2 - n^2) = m-n$. This leads to $$k(m+n)(1 + m^2 - n^2) = m^2 - n^2$$ which in turn means $$(1 + x) | x$$ where $x = m^2 - n^2$. This has a rather limited number of possible solutions.